# How to read and write BSON documents in Android

Tags: android, bson

Dear All,
         Can anyone tell me that how to read and write BSON document in Android.
Thanks in Advance.
Irfan

Answer (score 1):

Not a ton of choices: I'd recommend the https://github.com/paracycle/BsonME library (as linked from http://bsonspec.org/#/implementation). Seems kinda sparse out there, unless you want to either swallow the entire mongodb driver or incorporate all of the Jackson library into your code, and I don't know what kind of file size/dependencies those impose.

EDIT: Let us know what you find, kind of interested in this myself.